# Can we use #if 0 in header file?

Tags: c, header

I have some code need to be removed, and I used:

```
#if 0
#endif
```

to remove it from the source code, but when I try to remove it from header files, there are some errors like:

> `expected unqualified-id before '/' token`

I checked it, is fine around the line it complains, so what is the problem?

Comment: Show the problematic code.

Comment: Yes you can. And the error is somewhere else. Maybe after disabling that piece of code...

Comment: If you checked, and it's fine, then surely the compiler must be broken. We can't help you check, since you're not showing the code.

Comment: maybe you are declaring a variable inside the disabled code and using it in some division operation.

Comment: You have to share at least the code where the error happens otherwise we can not help you

Comment: @Gordon why you have deleted the answer. the answer is adequate with the SO clauses. If there is something in the answer you cna say it and I will fix it. Explain

Answer (score 1):

The answer is YES.

### But...

Be careful, you might disabled an important piece of code, for example:

```
#define XYZ

#if 0

#undef  XYZ
#define XYZ 1

#endif

int main()
{
    XYZ / 1;  // error: expected primary-expression before '/' token
}
```

Compiler ignores the codes between `#if 0` and `#endif` and it will not see `#define XYZ 1`.

Comment: this should return `undefined parameter` error in the compilation and the OP get `expected unqualified-id before '/' token`

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your question

> Can we use #if 0 in header file?

The answer is yes you can

And the error you get it's from other cause.